# User defined type not defined for file directory

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I keep getting an error at Dim fd As FileDialog

ive checked the references and i have Microsoft Office 12.0 Object library checked. is there a different reference im supposed to have checked for this?

Im using Access 2007 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bit weird. Alternatively you can use

```
Dim f As Object
Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
```

That way you don't need early binding.